# Creating new form over parent form

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to create a form over the parent form so that wherever the parent form is the new form will be created in the same place. I've looked around and have so far found this:

```
private void Cleaning_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
        this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        form2.Location = new Point(this.Left, this.Top);
        this.Close();
}
```

But I can't figure out how to fully close the old parent form without closing the newly created form.

Here is my old code:

```
private void Cleaning_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    this.Hide();
    Cleaning c = new Cleaning();
    c.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

OK the main problem now is that the this.Close closes both the forms and I really need some advice.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well your second code snippet doesn't have the `Location` setter... and note that using `ShowDialog` will block until the dialog has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

The form you are trying to close is the main form of the application  so if you close it all other form will close with it

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 form1 = new Form1(); 
        Form1 form2 = new Form2(); 
        Application.Run(form1);
       // It will run form1 until it close then run the form2 
        Application.Run(form2);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
private void Cleaning_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
        this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        form2.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y);
        this.Close();
}
```

And change property of new form: StartPosition => Manual

Hope this help !

Comment: It only works if I remove the this.Close otherwise it exits before the new form can create and if I remove the this.Close when I exit the newly created form the application doesn't fully exit because the original form is hidden.

Comment: Why you want using c.ShowDialog();

Comment: It was in a tutorial I used but im using your code now. The main probelm is that this.Close closes both the forms.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Hide` property to hide the parent form after `Show` of child form.

Add `Application.Exit()` to the close button of the child form. (if you want to exit from child form)

Do not add the `this.Close()` in the parent form.

PS: Tell me if I missed something.

Comment: How would I make `Application.Exit` perform on the child form for the windows button.

Comment: Write it in **close** button of the child form. But it should **Ask user** first (using `messageBox.Show()` and `DialogResult`) before closing. If you dont have close button, then add **Ask user** part in `Form_Closing` event and use `e.Cancel` in `Form_Closing` event to cancel exiting if user opted to not exit.

Comment: Nope it seems to be a lost cause. I'm not to worried by it now though, thanks for the help.